# react native app created in VS App Center crashes on launch (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I have a react native app created in VS App Center which crashes on launch (Android). The debug version works fine.

One interesting error in the logcat is this:

```
11-03 16:22:37.543 17977 18007 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
```

This error doesn't make sense since it shouldn't need Metro server since it is building the release variant in App Center.

I am using react native 0.60.6.

Full logcat [here](https://filebin.net/fugm5ywy9w1n58ad/log3.txt?t=pztpx45p)

Source code [here](https://github.com/joshua-augustinus/rn-training-video)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it was the tools version of gradle. I had it set to version 4. If I lower it it doesn't crash:

android/build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
```